# Does Browsers blocking Java affect Scala code

Tags: scala

Scala beginner; no practical experience with Java. Since many browsers block Java, does this affect Scala web applications since Scala uses Java libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one case which user unknown's answer doesn't cover is that you can write code which you want to execute in the browser using Scala and translate it into Javascript with [Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/) (there are also [ways to do the same with Java and other JVM languages](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS#javajvm)). This wouldn't be blocked.

Answer (score 2):

Web applications are executed on the server, while users may only block on their client, that is, Java-Applets.

So, no, it doesn't affect neither Scala, nor Java web applications.